# Is there a way to eval single MongoDB command on multiple servers?

Tags: mongodb, eval

I need to execute the same command (`db.stats()`) on multiple servers. Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
mongo <host> --eval 'db.stats()' --quiet
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to eval this command on multiple servers at once and get the output of all of them, instead of running the command multiple times for each server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a lot of ways that you **could** do this. Probably the best and most flexible way is to script this using one of the [MongoDB drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/), e.g. write a Python, Node, Java, Perl, Ruby, etc. program/script to collect the data that you're trying to collect. Or you could externally script the mongo shell via your from a shell script (e.g. bash).

From within the mongo shell, you can also connect to another mongo instance using the [connect()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/connect/) method.